# How to pull/fetch a branch from github to local?

Tags: git, github

I need to switch to a local brach master to a github branch feature/ABF-3-project-structure

I run the below command.

```
git pull feature/ABF-3-project-structure
```

[image: this is output of the command]

[image]

Please help me out. I have tried for at least 3 hours but still no luck

Thanks,
Enamul

Comment: I don't see a remote branch called `feature/ABF-3-project-structure` in your branch listing. Remote branches are pulled just by doing `git pull`, but you usually need to branch them locally if you want to work on it (usually a remote-tracking local branch, so you get all new updates from upstream and possibly push back if you have write access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding ssh key to github. I previously working on git with out setting ssh key on github.

It's very simple. I just added the ssh key and run the previous commands. That solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but switching to the mentioned branch can be done with the following code: `git checkout feature/ABF-3-project-structure`.

Comment: feature/ABF-3-project-structue is created on the github. Now I need to access this branch from local

Comment: My project manager created a branch on github by the name feature/ABF-3-project-structure. But I could not pull/fetch it .
That's my problem. :((

Comment: Okay. Now I see it. I think following these steps could be the solution: 1, create a new folder, and use 'git init'
2, git remote add feature [address of your git repository]
3, git pull feature feature/ABF-3-project-structure

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
git pull {repo} {remotebranchname}:{localbranchname}

git pull origin abc:abc
```

In case when you are on the master branch you also should first checkout a branch:

```
 git checkout -b abc
```

this should create new branch "abc" from the master and directly check it out. than you should run:

```
 git pull origin abc
```

to pull the new branch to your local abc branch

Comment: Tried these commands but the output is 
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref feature/ABF-3-project-structue

Comment: `git checkout -b feature/ABF-3-project-structue` and then `git pull origin master`